# Alineacion desfasada

Tags: html, css

Soy bastante novato en la programación y no se como solucionar un pequeño offset que tengo al centrar un texto. En la parte de informacion de abajo, en la imagen, los logos de instagram estan centrados (los he medido hasta con regla) pero el texto queda ligeralmente desplazado a la izquierda no se porque motivo.

[Imagen donde se ve el offset en el texto de la parte de abajo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4wYK.png)

[Link al zip de la web](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qqrsrJ2t7ozN7IRBDuVchj0jWByrw0TA/view?usp=sharing)

Los he centrado siguiendo un codigo de  css que encontre en el foro y para muchos elementos me ha funcionado.

Aqui esta el codigo de todo lo de abajo, el texto y los logos de isntagram.

```
<div id=bottom> </div>
<div id=lineasuperiorbottom></div>
<div>
  <p id=infobottomtexto>mingographics@gmail.com<br><br>Madrid, España<br><br><br><br><br>©2020 by Rodrigo Minguez</p>
</div>

<div class="logosinsta">
  <a class=instalogo2 href="https://www.instagram.com/mingo_entropy/"><img class="logosinsta" src="resources/socials/instablack.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="logosinsta">
<a class=instalogo href="https://www.instagram.com/mingo_graphics/">  <img class="logosinsta" src="resources/socials/instablack.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Y este es el css de todos esos elementos, que he hecho con el mismo codigo que como digo arriba saque del foro.

```
#infobottomtexto{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:22px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.instalogo{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 95px;
  left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left:50%;
margin-right: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;

}

.instalogo2{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 95px;
  left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left:50%;
margin-right: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;

}
.logosinsta{
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No esta bien que uses un absolute para algo tan simple, aqui algunas cosas que podrian solucionar tu problema

1. los contenedores deben de tener un width del 100% con text-align:center; para que tus elementos se mantengan al centro.
2. a los iconos de instagram, como los agregas, con un icon de fontawesome o parecido o imagen, en cualquiera de los casos al contenedor ponle un width 100% y text-align: center; a los iconos dales una clase igual a ambos, por ejemplo, instalogo y usa ese para ambos, solo tienes que darle un display: inline-block; y jugar con el padding o margin.

El width 100% es solo un ejemplo, pero la idea es que todos los elementos de tipo bloque tengan el mismo tamaño, para que cuando alineas al centro queden todos en el mismo punto. Usar un absolute para algo tan simple solo complicara mantener los elementos en su pocision.

Por ultimo, si no quieres hacer esos cambios prueba con verificar el padding o margin de tus contenedores, talvez tienen de mas y por eso da esa sensacion de mal alineados.

Si tienes la url de tu sitio haria mas facil verificar el problema

Comment: Con text-align probe primero de todo, pero tampoco me los centra bien, se queda desfasado no se porque y no consigo hacer que el inline funcione, me pone ambos logos superpuestos y ni con pading ni margin ni inline se separan. No se que estoy haciendo mal, pero es que ni se centran

Comment: Puedes compartir tu sitio, o comparti un zip de tu html, pued que sea por alguna regla que sobreescriba tus css, pero me es dificil saber sin poder ver los elementos y tu codigo en general

Comment: No tengo la web subida a nongun lado, esta en local, he adjuntado arriba del post el zip, la parte de abajo con la que tengo el problema esta en el archuvo de social.html y el css de la parte de abajo es bottomstyles.css

Comment: Veo que hay muchos problemas de pocision de elementos, revisa los elementos pero lo hare en la noche, hasta entonces este atento a su pregunta

Comment: No te preocupes, que empece a programar hace 3 dias y soy muy novato, tu dime que errores ves y voy investigando, que lo hago como puedo.

Comment: Bien, primero investiga sobre responsive design, no tienes la meta etiqueta 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 

que es la que se encarga de permitir que tus elementos sean responsive, si la pones podras usar los tamaños en porcentajes %, mi recomendaciones es ponerle a tus contendores un tamaño del 90% con margin: auto; y un max-width de 1200px, de esa forma no importa de que tamaño sea tu pantalla, mentendra un tamaño especifico y sera dinamico en tamaños menos a 1200px.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115818/discussion-between-jefferzon-bol-and-rodriminguez).